# How to keep the ball on zigzag movement?

Tags: unity

I recently make a zig-zag movement it works perfectly but after the ball hit the collider or obstacle the ball is changing their direction like just forward, not zig-zag anymore I've tried to update the velocity after collide but it's same, also I have tried to constant the magnitude but that's not what I want

here my script

```
public float magnitude;
    public float forwardSpeed;
    public float horizontalSpeed;

    private Vector2 horizontalAxis;
    private Vector2 negationVector;

    public Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public m_GameManager _GameManager;

    public bool isOver = false;

    private void Awake()
    {

        horizontalAxis = Vector2.right;
        negationVector = new Vector2(-1f, 0);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _GameManager = FindObjectOfType<m_GameManager>();
        UpdateVelocity();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            ReverseHorizontalVector();
            UpdateVelocity();
        }
    }

    private void ReverseHorizontalVector()
    {
        horizontalAxis *= negationVector;
    }

    private void UpdateVelocity()
    {
        Vector2 velocity = GetCompositeVelocity();
        rb2d.velocity = velocity;
    }

    private Vector2 GetCompositeVelocity()
    {
        Vector2 forward = Vector2.up * forwardSpeed;
        Vector2 horizontal = horizontalAxis * horizontalSpeed;
        Vector2 composite = (forward + horizontal);

        return Vector2.ClampMagnitude(composite, magnitude);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        UpdateVelocity();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Goal"))
        {
            _GameManager.IncreaseScore();
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("L") || collision.gameObject.CompareTag("R") || collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Death")
            || collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(_GameManager.waitAfterDeath());
            isOver = true;
        }
    }
```

[image: The error like this]

like I said before the ball zig zag but after colliding the movement change like that.

[image]

[image: I wabt like This]

Comment: Have you tried adding debug functions to make sure your OnCollisionEnter2D function is being called properly? Also is there any reason you cannot just set the velocity every frame. If I had to guess at the issue, it looks like your code is pushing the ball into the collider which causes it to look like it is going straight. Then as soon as the collision ends it uses the last physics velocity the system calculated which is straight. Maybe you need to check OnCollisionExit2D as well for setting the velocity the first time it comes out of a collision state.

Comment: yes the OnCollisionEnter2d is work properly

Comment: What is the velocity in the OnCollisionExit2D function?

Comment: I've tried to implement OnCollisionExit2D as you said and it's working.

Comment: working as in fixed or working as in you have the correct velocity but the ball is still not moving correctly?

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson fixed then ball movement by keeping zig-zag when colliding thanks

Comment: Nicely done, but you should post an answer to the question if you figured it out. Never know if someone might run into the same problem and it's always good for earning yourself a little street cred on these stack exchanges.

Comment: Please do not add "(solved)" into the title of your question. Having an answer and marking that answer as Accepted by clicking the green checkmark is how we identify solved questions here, not by changing their titles. You'll be able to accept your own answer after a short waiting period.

Answer (score 0):

solved by add

```
private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    UpdateVelocity();
}
```